# Understanding VBJSON class set up in Excel 2010

Tags: json, vba

I have downloaded and set the JSON parser for VB6 from this website:
[VB-JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

I cannot understand how this module works. I successfuly set it in Excel 2010 and I think I also understand the JSON format but I don't know how this class extracts the items. I tried to parsed the following text in the JSON format

```
{"realms":[{"type":"pvp","population":"low","queue":false,"wintergrasp":{"area":1,"controlling-faction":1,"status":0,"next":1356724174636},"tol-barad":{"area":21,"controlling-faction":1,"status":0,"next":1356723246779},"status":true,"name":"Kor'gall","slug":"korgall","battlegroup":"Cruelty / Crueldad","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"Europe/Paris"},{"type":"pve","population":"medium","queue":false,"wintergrasp":{"area":1,"controlling-faction":0,"status":0,"next":1356724425638},"tol-barad":{"area":21,"controlling-faction":0,"status":0,"next":1356723369780},"status":true,"name":"Alonsus","slug":"alonsus","battlegroup":"Cruelty / Crueldad","locale":"en_GB","timezone":"Europe/Paris"}]}
```

A browser will return this content when the following address is used:
[Alonsus, Kor'gall](http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/realm/status?realms=Alonsus,Kor%27gall)

I wrote a code similar to this

```
Dim objJSON As Object
...
strData = objJSON.Item("Realms")(1).Item("Type")
```

but it causes errors: "Object variable or With block variable not set". I expected to get "pve" value. I am confused because it starts with an object name "realms" followed by an Array. The array is supposed to be returned as a collection. I would be grateful for any help with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set objJSON = JSON.Parse(jsonFromUrl)
strData = objJSON.Item("realms").Item(1).Item("type")
```

Keys inside json is case-sensitive.